# I have been using SQL Parameters without using Prepare in .NET. Is this bad? Why should I use it?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, prepared-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pros and Cons of using SqlCommand Prepare in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449827/pros-and-cons-of-using-sqlcommand-prepare-in-c)

Here is an example. This seems to work fine but I just stumbled upon Prepare() and I'm wondering if I should be using it.

> con.Open();
>   cmd.Connection = con;
>   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl ([val], [desc]) OUTPUT INSERTED.tbl_id VALUES (@val, @desc); ";
>   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", AccountSession.Current.UserId);
>   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Desc);
>   retVal.id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();