# Benefit of using Prepare statement in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using the parameterized select query for querying the mysql database. And below is the c# code I am using

```
 public static void ValidateName(MySqlConnection conn,List<Employee> EmpList, string Grp)
{
    string selectQuery = "Select Name from Employee where Group = @Group  AND @Name in (FirstName, LastName);";
     using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
        {
         for (int i = 0; i < EmpList.Count; i++)
          {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Grp;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmpList[i].Name;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lineList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
            if (lineList.Count <=0)
            {
               WriteValidationFailure(EmpList[i], "Failed");
            }
    }       
    }
  }
```

What is the benefit of using the cmd.Prepare(); does that improve my code in any ways. Also I need to know if I am having multiple functions like above in my program and everytime  giving `using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))` inside in the individual functions add any complexity to the code? I am new to creating database connection from the c# and not sure about how much complexity my code adds.

Comment: where is  cmd.Prepare();  in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly and efficiently reuse a prepared statement in C# .NET (SQL Server)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972375/how-to-correctly-and-efficiently-reuse-a-prepared-statement-in-c-sharp-net-sql)

Comment: @AkashKC I havent added the cmd.Prepare(); yet but checking if it would make any efficiency  to my code

Comment: @Usman I have two questions. Can you please help me with this

Comment: Check out for pros and cons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449827/pros-and-cons-of-using-sqlcommand-prepare-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Prepare()` method is most useful when you wanna execute a parametric **`StoredProcedure`** in database, When you call the `Prepare()`, ADO try to check parameter type and size with thing you provided already, It use full to avoid making database busy before your are not sure about procedure parameters. Give you gain in performance.