# Microsoft SQL server: INSERT to table with 's

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax

```
string sql = "Insert Into mytable" + $" (Id, Name, otherName) Values" + 
            $" ('{id}','{name}','{otherName}')";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

And my problem is: some of my data has things like: in "otherName" columns, which will have some like "Mike's car".
SQL server will put error on "'s", which I dont know how to fix on my code.

Thank you for reading. And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: instead of `Mike's car` try `Mike''s car` two single quotes. Whereas you must use Parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pros and Cons of using SqlCommand Prepare in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449827/pros-and-cons-of-using-sqlcommand-prepare-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I am doing is parsing data from a source which I dont have any control on it. So, I need to figure out how to fix that with code. And by the way, how to parameterize it that way?

Comment: And thank you very much, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Parameters, you are leaving yourself open to a SQL Injection attack:

```
// These come from whatever your source which you have no control over.
int id = 12345;
string name = "Andrew";
string otherName = "Fred";

var sql = "Insert Into mytable (Id, Name, otherName) Values (@id, @name, @otherName)
using (var sqlQuery = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection)) 
{

    sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otherName", otherName);

    sqlQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add the reason why this is the correct answer: parameters know how to correctly handle (escape) values in such a way that no values can break your SQL command.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.